# How can I calculate the number of commits that changed a line in git?

Tags: git

I'm looking for a transposed `git blame`, so to say. I need to tell whether a line was 'hot' - changed many times - or not. All solutions I googled focus on statistics like *lines per author* where I need *authors per line*. I understand no solution will be perfect when you consider moved/added/deleted lines, but I'm not looking for perfect - I don't want to reinvent the wheel and I don't believe nobody asked that question before.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly; `git log` has a option `-L` which allows you limiting to show log of specific line in a file.

Wire that in with some grep you should be able to tell how many times a line was changed.

```
git log --oneline -L 71,71:package.json | grep diff | wc -l
```

This will tell you how many commits have changed line number 71 in package.json.

I used grep to make the log go one line leaving out the actual details. Can look for better option.